# HD Tune last block not scanned

Tags: hard-drive, bad-sectors

Why is it only on some HDDs and some Removable Devices do I have the last block in the **Error Scan** unchecked?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: It's probably the visualisation, the drive might not divide evenly in 166kb chunks. I think it's "good enough" as it is. Pick a bigger size for visualisation: not using the full size of the visualisation area effectively. Pick a smaller size for visualisation: it won't fit in the space given.

Comment: @ta.speot.is
But doesn't this mean the partitions are not alligned? If hdtune can't properly divide the chunks this means the first partition was created at the wrong offset right?

Comment: If you had two cells on screen to visualise scanning a 9kb drive, it probably makes just as much sense to make each cell represent 9kb than 5kb, or any other value. So you'd have one, unfilled block.